# "Forking" a single master file to multiple variations under version control

Tags: git, svn, version-control, versioning

I'm trying to determine whether this workflow I'm looking for even exists. Perhaps I'm just not coming up with the right name for the concept.

### Description of workflow

A bunch of co-workers are organizing a fantasy yak racing league. Because yak racing has a long history and is deeply stepped in tradition, we have constant about which major ruleset variation to follow (Tibetan or Mongolian), and whether body oiling is allowed. In the end, it is decided that the league will be subdivided by locality, and each sub-league is allowed, for internal matches, to modify rules as they see fit.

#### Setup of documents

When the organizers drafted the rule document, they decided that there should be a *master* ruleset that will be observed for the post-season, along with a unique modified version for each sub-league that is observed internally.

The administrative staff made the following ruleset:

```
Important rules for the whole yak racing league!
- racing yaks must wear red bandanas
- at most 2 bottles of oil allowed at pit stops
- no gongs
… etc
```

Meanwhile, the Tibetan sub-league really wants to use gold bandanas, and they have a bigger problem with butter tea abuse compared to oil. Instead of copying the master ruleset, the administrative staff **forked** the original document and applied changes so it looks like this:

```
Important rules for the Tibet yak racing sub-league!
- racing yaks must wear red *or gold* bandanas
- at most 2 bottles of butter tea allowed at pit stops
- no gongs
… etc
```

The Mongolians somehow always ring gongs on Thursdays for traditional reasons, so their sub-league version of the rules is **forked** again, and modified to look like this:

```
Important rules for the Mongolia yak racing sub-league!
- racing yaks must wear red bandanas
- at most 2 bottles of oil allowed at pit stops
- no gongs (except on Thursdays)
- bow and arrows are allowed on racers for decoration
… etc
```

and on it goes for the 20 or so sub-leagues.

#### Merging upstream changes

After a few days, somehow the legal department caught wind of the hot fantasy yak racing action, and insisted that we add a legal disclaimer to to all the ruleset documents, pointing out that with adequate disclaimer they can allow 5 bottles of oil without ramifications to the organizers. Also, they felt silly that there was a blanket ban on gongs (it was snuck in mysteriously during an extended lunch break). The master ruleset now looks like this:

```
Important rules for the whole yak racing league!
**super important legal disclaimer**
- racing yaks must wear red bandanas
- at most 5 bottles of oil allowed at pit stops
… etc
```

Because the administrators were smart enough to **fork** this master file when modifying the sub-league rules, instead of having to edit all 20 or so sub-league rules to reflect the changes, they just **merged** the changes made to the master document *into* the sub-league rules.

The Tibetan version merged successfully (on the word level), and now looks like this:

```
Important rules for the Tibet yak racing sub-league!
**super important legal disclaimer**
- racing yaks must wear red *or gold* bandanas
- at most 5 bottles of butter tea allowed at pit stops
… etc
```

while the Mongolian version will have merge conflicts because it also modified the "no gongs" ruleset. After manually resolving this, it now looks like:

```
Important rules for the Mongolia yak racing sub-league!
**super important legal disclaimer**
- racing yaks must wear red bandanas
- at most 5 bottles of oil allowed at pit stops
- bow and arrows are allowed on racers for decoration
… etc
```

Just like that, a tedious task was reduced down to a 5 minute job. The administrative staff then spent the rest of the day celebrating by browsing Reddit.

#### Summary of characteristics

I can't really think of any existing system (open source, non-monolithic) that enables this:

- Downstream modifications can be relatively complex and may not be simple insertions, so a templating system isn't going to work without the documents looking unwieldily very quickly.
- There's too many different "forks" to effectively manage if we just make each file standalone branches that modify the master file. There may easily be hundreds of different variations.
- The *master* file should be standalone and modifiable as-is. It's no-good to procedurally generate the downstream documents, if only because this encodes all the dependency of the downstream documents into the master file, and that becomes unmaintainable very quickly.

### Question

1. Does the workflow I just described have a proper name?
2. What kind of tools facilitate this kind of workflow?
3. Can I already accomplish this with existing version control tools?

Comment: You have to think, read and use not VCS (manageable history of changes), but SCM (Software Configuration Management): you have not forks, but different *configurations* (sets of atomic rules + rule-modifications as objets)

Comment: I did some heavy searching over the weekend, but I don't see many tools that are either generic enough (many are tied specifically to system configurations) or lightweight enough for my needs. Perhaps I'm overlooking some obvious examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of branching scheme seems to come up a lot, and to me it looks like an antipattern. Branches work best when they're short-lived (topic branches) or rarely-changing (release branches/tags). The setup you're describing here -- where long-lived branch-ish-things act like "parallel histories" that are constantly getting rebased -- it doesn't scale. Each branch has implicit dependencies on master, which are invisible until later when you get to the merge. The "manually resolving" step you describe in your Mongolian example isn't too bad when it's just a line or two, but as soon as a branch tries to maintain any serious changes (say, British vs American spelling throughout the document), it's going to turn into constant pain. Look at the requirements:

> - **Downstream modifications can be relatively complex** and may not be simple insertions...
> - ...There may easily be **hundreds of different variations.**

Tools can't handle that for you. You're going to have a hundred merge conflicts every time you make a change, and all of them are going to need a human, because computers don't know what you *meant* by your changes.

If you're serious about the hundreds-of-variations thing, I think you have two real options:

1) Admit that these are really separate documents, and stop trying to automate the merge process. This is probably what would happen naturally. Your British spelling maintainer would realize that that `git rebase` is always going to run into useless conflicts, and they'd learn to just read the original diffs and redo all the changes by hand. At this point, your branches are basically independent repos.

2) Actually generate all the different variants. Part of this is being clever and recognizing ways to avoid repeating yourself. (Say, each branch* can have a substitution dictionary for spelling changes, with clean shared logic to actually run the substitutions.) But the more important part of this is *forcing* all the different variants to share structure. "You want to swap rules 3 and 4? Tough, you can't. Because we don't want to maintain another stupid boolean/map/interface."

Ok I lied you have three:

3) Use `git rerere`. I have basically no idea how that works, but this is the problem it solves. I suspect you'd end up with a lot of Very Important state that doesn't actually live under version control, which frightens me.

* If you actually go with generation, the variants shouldn't be branches anymore. They should be directories of data under a single project, with one consistent history.

Comment: Ahhh if you had commented a day earlier I would have rewarded your post the bounty. It's the only one that actually addresses the specific issue without turning into a branching tutorial.

Comment: And thank you for the `git rerere` tip. Do you know of any tools that help automate management of these many "parallel" branches? Part of my reason for thinking "nah… this can't just be as simple as branches" is that you end up with a unwieldily number of branches that none of the current UI interfaces (incl. Github) are designed to handle.

Comment: The best tool for automating a git workflow is honestly bash. Git is very scriptable. Most commands with output take a `-z` flag to make their output null-delimited, for safe parsing by tools like `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very similar to [git branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).  They are a concept that models fairly well this concept of multiple downstream versions, all derived from a master version.

In this example, the administrative staff would start by making the basic rules:

```
git init
<Create the RULES file>
git add RULES
git commit -m "Initial rules"
```

Then the Tibetans create a branch for their own set of the rules, based off the original branch (which defaults to the name master):

```
git checkout -b tibet master
<Edit the RULES file>
git add RULES
git commit -m "Updates for Tibet"
```

And similarly, the Mongolians create their own branch:

```
git checkout -b mongolia master
<Edit the RULES file>
git add RULES
git commit -m "Updates for Mongolia"
```

When the lawyers want to add their disclaimer, they add another commit to the master branch.

```
git checkout master
<Edit the RULES file>
git add RULES
git commit -m "Add legal disclaimer"
```

In order for these changes to take effect on the branches, they have to be merged in.

```
git checkout tibet
git merge master
```

Unfortunately, since git operates at the line level, not the word level, there are pretty severe merge conflicts at this point.  In a situation without such high modification density, this would work out better.

In git, there is another means of "merging" branches called a rebase.  When working on the tibet branch, *merging* master will cause new commits on master to be applied *after* the commits made on the tibet branch, and *rebasing* on master will cause the new commits to master to be applied *before* the commits made on the tibet branch.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't see this part of my post? "There's too many different "forks" to effectively manage if we just make each file standalone branches that modify the master file. There may easily be hundreds of different variations."

Comment: I took this to mean that there needed to be an automatic way of incorporating modifications to the master branch on the regional branches.  The merge process (aside from manual conflict resolution) can be scripted, so there is only one additional step (run the merge script) after each modification to the master branch.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using modified *versions* (which you then have to sync/merge for ever after), why not use separate documents;

- common rules
- Tibetan alterations
- Mongolian alterations.

This will largely prevent conflicts.

If having a single file is an absolute necessity, you can e.g. write a script to merge the common rules and the subleague specific alterations into a combined file that is *not* kept in git. (But the components to generate it are.)

Comment: I would if I could, but unfortunately there's technical reasons why I couldn't just use a templating system (including but not limited to what I alluded in my original post), which is essentially what you described.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the workflow I just described have a proper name?

Yes. What you called "forking" is usually called "branching" at this scale. What you called "merging" is normally called "merging", too. So the Tibetan subleague has **branched** their own version **off** the master ruleset and they can **merge** the updated master ruleset into their own at any time.

> What kind of tools facilitate this kind of workflow?

(Distributed) version control systems like Git and Mercurial.

> Can I already accomplish this with existing version control tools?

Yes, just put the master ruleset on the master branch and have each subleague have their own branch starting from the master branch. Merge the master branch into each of the subleague branches when the master ruleset is updated.

As far as I know the only limitation is that these systems can merge at the line level but not at the word level. The only difference that would make in your example, is that the Tibetan team would have to manually merge `at most 5 bottles of oil allowed at pit stops` from the master version with `at most 2 bottles of butter tea allowed at pit stops` from their own version. Apart from that, you get all the conveniences that you describe.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't see this part of my post? "There's too many different "forks" to effectively manage if we just make each file standalone branches that modify the master file. There may easily be hundreds of different variations."

Comment: To be honest I don't see why that is a showstopper. If having to manually resolve merge conflicts on each branch/fork is not too much asked from the subleagues, then surely merging in the master branch in the first place isn't either?